# how link the wordpress plugin to a menu link?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

In wordpress how can we link a pulgin to menu link in the fronedn.

In joomla while creating a menu link we have the option to select the component and paticular view.

like that do we have any specific way to do in wordpress

In the admin section i placed the code to add,edit and delete the teams and it athletes

Now in the front end i need to display the list of Teams Under Menu link Teams

when clicked on the team name need to display the team details and athlete list of that teams

Comment: What do you mean, linking a plugin to menu link? Joomla and WP differ greatly. In joomla you don't have 'pages' in traditional sense. Every page is a menu item, that you populate with modules, articles and plugins. In wordpress you have actual pages, posts, and menus that can be either pages, categories (for blogs) and links.

Comment: dingo_d, thanks for the reply. the admin part of the pulgin was completed. now i need to the frontend code actually in the admin we add team,athletes related to the teams. we need to display the all team under team menu link and athletes and athletes menu, how can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean how can you link a plugin to the wp-admin? There is documentation here:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page

You'll use add_menu_page() and check out the documentation for parameter usage.

Comment: Lucas, thanks for the reply. the admin part of the pulgin was completed. now i need to the frontend code actually in the admin we add team,athletes related to the teams. we need to display the all team under team menu link and athletes and athletes menu, how can i do it?

Comment: It sounds like you just need to create a function that shows what you want in the admin. The documentation describes how to do that:

"The function must be referenced in one of two ways:
1. if the function is a member of a class within the plugin it should be referenced as array( $this, 'function_name' )
2. in all other cases, using the function name itself is sufficient"